# How to map from a class type to a list?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I'm trying to improve my game's rendering by bulk rendering the textures of blocks of the same type.

Each block in my game is defined by a class in the format **BlockWood**, which all **extend** from the class **Block**.

I currently have a map between the different block classes/types, and an ArrayList which contains the positions of all the blocks of that type, on the map.

```
HashMap<Block, ArrayList<Vector2f>> blockMap = new HashMap<Block, ArrayList<Vector2f>>();
```

Using this, I can loop through the map, bulk rendering each type of block, speeding up my rendering.

This approach however, doesn't work. I want to be able to access the ArrayList's using a **dummy** class as so -

```
blockMap.get(BlockWood.class);
```

Is there any efficient way I can map a class type to an ArrayList? Or will I just have to map the class string representations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) as the key type. Your current implementation is using a `Block` instance as the key. Where as using `Class` will use the type of `Block` as the key.

Comment: Would this be more or less efficient than just using a String?

Comment: @LiamE-p: I don't know, but you could test it. One advantage of `Class` over `String` is that the set of strings is much larger than the set of classes that implement `Block`. Therefore `String` leaves you more open to using a key that does not have a value.

Answer (score 1):

Your map is not between class and list. It maps instance of `Block` to list. So, you always have to use instance of Block to access its lists.

`blockMap.get(new BlockWood());`

The question is just what will you get? You will get list that was previously stored in this map using this key.

BTW to improve your code change your map definition to:

`Map<Block, List<Vector2f>> blockMap = new HashMap<Block, List<Vector2f>>();`

Now you can use any type of list.

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that Map has two values (a key and value), while a List only has one value (an element).

Therefore, you can either get a list of all keys or list of all values.

for getting list of all keys, you can do

```
ArrayList<Block> keys = new ArrayList<Block>(blockMap.keySet());
```

for getting list of all Values, you can do

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Vector2f>> values = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Vector2f>>(blockMap.values());
```